# Create GridView programmatically with invisible imageview

Tags: android, gridview

I have a problem about android Gridview. I created a Gridview with imageview programmatically using getView function, but how can I set only one of the imageviews to be invisible?

Could you please provide any example to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have environment for android, so i did not try the following code but I think this works correctly.
I copied code from here [Android developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

        // I edit here, you can choose visible or not in here

        if (isVisibleImage(position) {
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  
        }
        return imageView;
    }

    private boolean isVisibleImage(int position) {
       return position == 0;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
       // resources
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it seems it will set all of imageviews to be invisible. If I only want to set one imageview only, such as set mThumBIds[0] to be invisible and mThumBIds[1] is visible.

Comment: Yes, that code is not enough for you, but i think you need if statement for set visible or invisible. I updated answer.